# Pandas read specific number of columns irrespective of data file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am reading a csv file as pandas dataframe like so:

```
num_cols = 80
df = pd.read_csv(read_path, compression='zip', header=None, sep=',', usecols=range(num_cols), low_memory=False)
```

Here, the number of columns is not fixed but I want to read the first 80 columns only, that's why I am using `usecols`. Now for files which have more than 80 columns this works fine, but for files having less than 80 columns, it's throwing this kind of error:

> Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: [64, 65,
> 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79]

How can I fix it? Ideally, I would like to read first 80 columns (the last few columns will simply contain NaNs).

Comment: while reading the file I do not think you can apply that logic. Since there are files with less than 80 cols, the best possible scenario here is to read the entire file and filter out only the first 80 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many pointed out, its better to read all the data first and then select first 80 rows. I achieved this by using `names=range(100)` as no row will have more than 100 columns, like so:

```
num_cols = 80
df = pd.read_csv(read_path, compression='zip', header=None, sep=',', names=range(100), low_memory=False)
df = df.iloc[: , :num_cols]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try a workaround by using `nrows=1` parameter:

```
num_cols = 80
cols = len(pd.read_csv(read_path, compression='zip', header=None, sep=',', low_memory=False, nrows=1).columns)
if cols < num_cols:
    num_cols = cols
df = pd.read_csv(read_path, compression='zip', header=None, sep=',', usecols=range(num_cols), low_memory=False)
```

Load the data but only the first row, check number of columns, then read whole thing without those additional columns.

Comment: You can read once and drop columns, instead of reading the file twice.

Comment: @DeepakGouda, that is true, but he seems to want to save memory. That is why he tries low_memory and asks to "not read" those columns in my understanding. First loading them and then dropping them won't achive that.

Comment: As the author has set `low_memory=False`, I assumed memory might not be an issue.